# Mysqli prepared statements Commands out of sync error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having a little problem with some MySQLi prepared statements, which are throwing me the "Commands out of sync error", which is quite annoying. I've read on this forum about using

```
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

or

```
$db->next_result();
```

but no one of them has worked for me, this is what i've tried so far. Those are 3 functions which are sending database's results to others, to finally send a mail

```
function getTable($id) {
    global $src;
    $s="SELECT TEMA FROM lp_tavolo WHERE ID=?";
    $q=$src->prepare($s) or die ($src->error);
    $q->bind_param('s',$id);
    $q->execute();
    $q->store_result();
    $q->bind_result($t);
    while($q->fetch()) {
        $q->close();
        $src->next_result();
        return $t;
    }
}

function getID($m) {
    global $src;
    $s="SELECT ID FROM lp_partecipante WHERE EMAIL=?";
    $q=$src->prepare($s) or die ($src->error);
    $q->bind_param('s',$m);
    $q->execute();
    $q->store_result();
    $q->bind_result($id);
    while($q->fetch()) {
        $q->close();
        $src->next_result();
        return $id;
    }
}

function getExternalID($m) {
    global $src;
    $s="SELECT ID_TAVOLO FROM lp_partecipante WHERE EMAIL=?";
    $q=$src->prepare($s) or die ($src->error);
    $q->bind_param('s',$m);
    $q->execute();
    $q->store_result();
    $q->bind_result($id);
    while($q->fetch()) {
        $q->close();
        $src->next_result();
        return $id;
    }
}


function sendCredentials($name,$mail,$code) {
        $table=getTable(getExternalID($mail));
}
```

The problem is that when i call the `getTable` function on a `getExternalID` function result, all I get is an "out of sync error". What should I do?

Comment: first, why do you use while, if you return with the first row value, why do not just fetch the row? And what, if there are no result. Then no return value. You should always return with something, for example false, if method has a return value, and then you need to check.

Comment: I know, this is kind of experimental, on my running version I'm actually using a row fetch. However, those functions are meant to be executing only when previous ones are working, so, if they are running, it means that there should always be a value to return. By the way, thanks for the tip, I've appreciated it :)